# cmake error with a software bam-window software

Tags: linux, github, build, cmake, cmake-gui

I am trying to install the tool bam-window but I am getting cmake error. I downloaded the bam-window-master.zip in linux. The link of the tool is hosted in git https://github.com/genome-vendor/bam-window. I downloaded and follow the below commands.

```
unzip bam-window-master.zip
cd bam-window-master
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

On doing cmake .. After compiling I for a while I get an error

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "1.7.10.4") 
CMake Error at cmake/GitHelper.cmake:15 (message):
  Failed to get git revision, abort: fatal: Not a git repository (or any
  parent up to mount point /scratch/GT)

  Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

  !
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (get_git_version_info)
```

How do I get rid of this and make the installation proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMakeLists.txt for this project assumes (unfortunately) that the source code is not downloaded as a zip file, but instead cloned from github.

So instead of using "Dowload ZIP" link, just clone it using regular GIT commands:

git clone https://github.com/genome-vendor/bam-window.git

Comment: fanstastic.. It works. I did not go in detail the CMakeLists.txt. Thanks a lot.